# How To Provide Terminal Report

Tags: discussion

Often, when I post something in forums, a 'report' is demanded in return (generated by a command in the Terminal). How to provide this? Is there a file saved on my computer? Where is it and how to insert it in the post?

Comment: Please give a specific example of what was "demanded".

Answer (score 10):

**Example #1: Show us output.**

*Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `apt list hello`*

1. Open a terminal
2. Input the command (`apt list hello`), then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Use your cursor to highlight the output, and **copy** it to your clipboard

   - Right-click, select `copy`
   - Or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
4. Return to your web browser. **Paste** the output into your AskUbuntu Question  (or answer) from the clipboard.

   - Right click, select `paste`
   - Or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

   **Pro Tip**: Paste information into your Question, where it can be edited and formatted. DON'T paste new information into comments, where it may be easily missed and cannot be formatted.
5. Edit the formatting into monospace font so the output appears correct.

   - Add three backticks (```) before and after the pasted section.
   - Or indent each line of the pasted section four spaces.
   - Or use AskUbuntu's `{ }` editing icon.

---

**Example #2: Show us a file**

*Please review your /var/log/apt/term.log. Show us any session with the error.*

1. Read the file. Don't dump an enormous file unless specifically requested.

**Small files or sections**: Copy-and-paste into your Question just like in Example #1.

**Large Files or sections**: Either copy/paste the file contents into https://paste.ubuntu.com/ or use the `pastebinit` command to save the file in Ubuntu's pastebin. Provide the pastebin link in your Question.